# База данных в кодировке utf8_general_ci

Tags: база-данных, кодировка

Как сделать MySQL базу данных в кодировке utf8_general_ci?

Answer (score 2):

```
$db = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8",$db);
```

Работает 100%.
А чтобы ставить по умолчанию в самой mysql, пользуйся phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Если создаёшь через phpMyAdmin, то при создании выбери эту кодировку в раскрывающемся списке "Сравнение".

Comment: а как скачать эту базу даннызх на ПК

Comment: В каком смысле "скачать"? Сделать дамп БД в phpMyAdmin можно в разделе "Экспорт".